# How can I send mail using Google SMTP (an error)

Tags: ios, xcode, smtp, gmail, smtpclient

I am trying send mail using google smtp. and attach an image there is my code and my error. 
My code:
    -(IBAction)gonder:(id)sender{

```
SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
testMsg.fromEmail = @"fromme@gmail.com";
testMsg.toEmail = @"tome@hotmail.com";
testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";
testMsg.requiresAuth = YES;
testMsg.login = @"myadress@gmail.com";
testMsg.pass = @"mypass";
testMsg.subject = @"had";
//testMsg.bccEmail = @"to@hotmail.com";
testMsg.wantsSecure = YES; 
testMsg.delegate = self;

NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                           @"FDDFAFAD",kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];

NSString *vcfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"vcf"];
NSData *vcfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:vcfPath];

NSDictionary *vcfPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/directory;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"test.vcf\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                         @"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"test.vcf\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,[vcfData encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"base64",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];

testMsg.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,vcfPart,nil];

[testMsg send];
```

and my error

[My Error!!](http://b1202.hizliresim.com/u/h/2rq37.png)

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Can you help me? And I need attach an image to this code.

Answer (score 0):

right from the example code:

http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/source/browse/trunk/SMTPSender/Classes/SMTPSenderAppDelegate.m

```
testMsg.wantsSecure = YES; // smtp.gmail.com doesn't work without TLS!
```

Comment: thanks at first but. sorry i dont know what does tls mean. i am so new   for ios.

Comment: TLS = transport layer security.  I'm assuming you want testMsg.wantsSecure = NO;